# Plural of “reason”

Tags: word-usage, plural-forms

> **Reason**: the cause of an event or situation or something that provides an excuse or explanation (From the Cambridge)

> A doesn’t provide an excuse or explanation for C.
>
> B doesn’t provide an excuse or explanation for C.
>
> A and B together provide an excuse or explanation for C.

In this case, can I say A and B are two **reasons** of C? Or should I say A and B are one **reason** of C?

Comment: You can only say there is one reason. That is explicit in your example.

Comment: @Dan Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

A and B together is a reason. A on its own is only part of the reason.

In practice, what is the reason or cause of something may have lots of implied parts.

> I woke up at 8:10.  That is the reason I was late for work.

Makes sense, but there are several other parts to the reason:

> I woke up at 8:00 and it takes me 30 minutes to get to work.

> I woke up at 8:00 and it takes me 30 minutes to get to work and work starts at 9:00.

> I woke up at 8:00 it takes me at least 15 minutes to get dressed and I have a job, and it takes me 30 minutes to get to work, and work starts at 9:00, and arriving after work starts is called "being late"....

On its own "getting up late" is really only part of the reason.  In real life we would say that it is *the* reason, and the other aspects are just context.

What is a "reason" and what is "context" is a matter for philosophers.

What is a cause and what is context is a matter for philosophers.

It might be correct to say that although "A and B is a reason" the "A is the reason" (because B is really part of the context)